# How to call functions after previous function is completed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, function, state

```
onPressed: () => {
     popUpForGroup("Add Group", null, context),
     print("pop up closed"),
     refreshPage(),
},
```

Here all three functions run at the same time.
I want to execute the refreshPage() function only when the popUpForGroup() execution ends.
popUpForGroup() is a function from another file, it displays a Dialogue box for adding a group to the database, and I wanted to refresh my current file( where I call the onpressed function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your popUpForGroup to async function like this.

```
Future<void> popUpForGroup({...}) async {...}
```

After that and inside your onPressed Function you can write this:

```
onPressed: () async => {
     await popUpForGroup("Add Group", null, context),
     print("pop up closed"),
     refreshPage(),
},
```

Comment: In my popUpForGroup function, I have another async function with await, I'm wondering if It will affect the execution time or something? (await in another await)

Comment: This could be affect to de user experience because the user could wait a lot of time.